# SOQL Statement to Query 'Session Security Levels' in session settings

Tags: soql

I am looking for a SOQL Statement to Query 'Session Security Levels' in session settings.

I want the state of these settings.

I tried the SessionSettings object but it is not returning the required data.
Please refer SS attached:
[image]

Comment: Please check this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_identityverificationevent.htm, this might be helpful to access. The above link is for the identityVerificationEvent object. To query you need special access according to the doc: Accessing this object requires either the Salesforce Shield or Salesforce Event Monitoring add-on subscription and the View Real-Time Event Monitoring Data user permission.

Comment: Thanks I will check if this fulfill my requirements